# How to access BuildConfig product flavor variables in React native android

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, react-native, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

Hi I followed the below link to create product flavours
[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@ywongcode/building-multiple-versions-of-a-react-native-app-4361252ddde5)

I set up a variable in the flavours and I am unable to access that in the code.

build.gradle.

```
 productFlavors {
    production {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        applicationId 'com.xxx.production'
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "MOCK_VERSION", "false"
        resValue "string", "MOCK_VERSION_ABCD", "false"
    }
    staging {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        applicationId 'com.xxx.staging'
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "MOCK_VERSION", "false"
        resValue "string", "MOCK_VERSION_ABCD", "false"
    }
    t3st {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        applicationId 'com.xxx.test'
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "MOCK_VERSION", "true"
        resValue "string", "MOCK_VERSION_ABCD", "true"
    }
}
```

I tried to access it in my Login.js file

```
import { BuildCofig } from 'react-native';

loginEndpointDecider = () => {
 if(BuildCofig.MOCK_VERSION){
   alert('MOCK_VERSION - true');
 }else{
   alert('MOCK_VERSION - false');
 }
}
```

To run the app

```
react-native run-android --variant=stagingDebug
```

I am trying to access `buildConfigField` `MOCK_VERSION`.

Could you please suggest how to get this working.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 2):

I've used [`react-native-build-config`](https://github.com/ismaeldcom/react-native-build-config) for this. Works well but remember to set up keep rules for the generated `BuildConfig` class if you are using proguard. The framework that inspired this library `react-native-config` also works but I had problems configuring the library to work with cocoapods when targeting >=0.56 RN.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I did have a look but this one supports only Android at the moment, I will be making the app work for iOS too so want something that would work for both.

Comment: I see. That wasn't clear in the original question. `react-native-config` with its `.plist` preprocessing step is what you need then. As I mentioned, I found this library problematic to include if you are using cocoapods but probably not impossible to get running.

Comment: okay thank you. but the approach I took. what is the problem with that? without using any external library

Comment: Not sure if BuildConfig is exposed over the bridge via the react-native package. (Plus there is a typo `BuildCofig`!) which is why it likely doesn't work.